# Seaborn FacetGrid col_wrap (wide to long) plotting issue

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to plot each row(in wide table) using Seaborn's FacetGrid and `col_wrap`.

First I convert wide to long:
-- `stack()` the wide data to a series, `s`.
-- use `get_level_values`
-- append the series to the dataframe

FacetGrid only plots the first plot though ?

```
dt1 = pd.DataFrame({'s1':[0,1,2,3,4], 's2':[4,2,3,6,7], 's3':[6,7,3,4,7] })
def fct(data):
    #toy model dataframe
    #dt1.index.names = ['ind']
    dt = data.stack()
    dt.index.names = ['i','s']
    ind = pd.Series( dt.index.get_level_values(0).values )
    sub = pd.Series( dt.index.get_level_values(1).values )
    dtt = pd.DataFrame( ind , columns=['ind'])
    dtt['sub'] = sub
    dtt['ind'] = ind
    dtt['dt'] = dt.values
    #dt.reindex(columns='v')
    print ( 'dt ', dtt.describe)
    g = sns.FacetGrid( dtt, col='sub', col_wrap=1, size=2, ylim=(0, 10) )
    g.map( sns.pointplot, 'ind', 'dt', color=".3", ci=None );
```

`

[image]

Comment: I have same issue with col_wrap=1, but works well with col_wrap=2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing that, but you should be able to do `row='sub'` and get exactly what you want.

By the way, you can use `factorplot` with `kind='point'` to draw this plot without using `FacetGrid` directly, it may be easier.